# Python : what is the equivalent python's requests.posts command for curl with --data-urlencode

Tags: python

I am trying to post some data to the server using the requests.post using python. But the request I have is in curl command and I need to convert that to the python's requests.post. But the catch here is the curl command is with the --data-urlencode and I did not find any solution for converting this --data-urlencode into pythons code. Please help me to convert the below curl command to pythons command.

The curl command is :

```
curl https://example.com/api/version1/cert/abccsr \

    -u {API_KEY}:{API_KEY_SECRET} \
    -X POST \
    -d company="xyz" \
    -d emp_name="abcdef" \
    --data-urlencode "abccsr=azlkjdllksdl+jl8lksehsd8vYZ7lo..."
```

I tried with the below python command with --data-urlencode inside data. but its not working. I dont know exactly how to convert this data-urlencode into python requests.post. Please let me know how to convert this curl command with --data-urlencode into python's requests.

```
mno = "azlkjdllksdl+jl8lksehsd8vYZ7lokhkjhdohs99kjhgsadjkahgfjhgsjhgdsjhwggfuy48992lkjf+jgskjhgsdjgasd1983kjjgds9hd893;iyajhf9ljasiulfljgwwiugfejgqwoiug"

data = [
        ('company', 'xyz'),

        ('emp_name', 'abcdef'),
        ('employ_id', 'emp_'+str(i)),
        ('--data-urlencode', "abccsr=" + mno )
]

response = requests.post('https://example.com/api/version1/cert/abccsr', data=data, auth = ('API_KEY', 'API_KEY_SECRET'))
```

Comment: here's a handy tool https://curl.trillworks.com/

Comment: This url converts curl command to python command but it does not convert the --data-urlencoding part of the command.

Answer (score 0):

Just encode the data first, with `quote_plus`:

```
import urllib.parse
data = [
        ('company', 'xyz'),
        ('emp_name', 'abcdef'),
        ('employ_id', 'emp_'+str(i)),
        ("abccsr", urllib.parse.quote_plus(mno))
]
```

Comment: Thanks nosklo. But I am using python 2.7 and there is no module for urllib.parse. How I can use the urllib.parse module in python 2.7.

Comment: in python 2 the `quote_plus` function is directly into `urllib` so `import urllib` and use `urllib.quote_plus` @shari

Comment: Thanks again for the reply nosklo. using urllib.quote_plus works but the response I get is 404 Bad request. "Invalid URL","description":"The URL you tried does not exist." But if I execute the same in curl command I will get the exact response what I am expecting. But it fails in python. I dont understand what is the problem here with python. Please help